# Какая разница  между apc и memcache?

Tags: кэширование, memcached, php

В интернете встречал, что сабж кеширует разные сущности. Насколько это правда?
Если можно развёрнутый ответ.

Как кешировать файл с помощью apc?
Как достать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

у них общее только слово "кеш".

- apc - это кеш для байт-кода php, чтоб
     интерпретатор не интерпретировал
     каждый раз заново, а выполнял уже
     интерпретированный код из кеша,
     работает как модуль для php.
- memcache - это хранилище
     ключ/значение в оперативной памяти,
     вешается на порт или unix-сокет.
- wikiпедия - очень познавательная
     энциклопедия. ) там много чего есть,
     ее стоит читать )

Comment: причина вопроса была вто, как использовать и то и другое в одном проекте?

Comment: @MuFF, их ведь одновременно использовать можно?)

Comment: А кто вам мешает? Как сказали уже, они кешируют совершенно разные вещи. Один - исполняемый байт-код,то есть, не будет заново парсить и выполнять ваш php-код, а просто запустит на выполнение то, что уже написали.

А другой будет держать в памяти все, что ВЫ захотите (пользователей, сесси, куски html).

Оба сделаны как модули к php, так что и то и другое из PECL вам не составит труда установить.

P.S.: В хайлоаде их не просто должны использовать, а обязаны использовать вместе